# Is PayPal's adaptive payments not working in India and Georgia?

Tags: paypal

At my company, an internet platform, we have a set up with Paypal adaptive payments allowing merchant across the world selling digital goods to local and international buyers, with a fee sent to us via adaptive payments.

According to PayPal's documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/

"You can use Adaptive Payments in any country where PayPal is accepted."

We have now had reports from potential merchants from both India and Georgia stating that they cannot make the connection to our service work with the PayPal accounts.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't it work with a simple PayPal account in these countries or do the potential merchants needs any special approval from Paypal or are there other prerequisites?

Comment: Both country can accept PayPal however, what was the exact error? DO you have any logs or something that useful to understand the problem?

Comment: There are no logs from the users, just reports that they cannot make the connection work. My problem is that I do not know what to tell them to do. Maybe they need a special business account or there are other prerequisites for using PayPal's Adaptive Payment in those countries that I do not know about.

Comment: In this case, I would strongly suggest you to files a ticket to PayPal MTS and they will assist you on this. Don't forget to include the email address of your client as well as the payKey from the error.

File it here : https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and link. I'll write them, as now we did some additional testing with their sandbox testing environment. We found 2 issues. 

1. We cannot create a test account for a user based in Georgia - even though the documentation say that Georgia is supported.

2. When I try creating a Indian test account and add is as recipient in our Adaptive payment set up, I get this error: "The primary receiver is based in a country that isn't enabled to send payments using balance" - which doesn't make sense to me, since nothing is going to be send from the account, only added to it.

Comment: India is a country where they can't use PayPal balance as their funding source. In your testing, the India Account should be put as a secondary receiver for all transaction in Adaptive. For Georgia, if you are creating the account of Sandbox from developer, the country might not be there but you can register the account from sandbox.paypal.com and then link it to your developer account.

Comment: thanks! it seems that changing the order of primary and secondary receiver solves the issue!